# How To Create a 'Host' folder and Prevent It From Being Deleted In Mac OSX

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal

case 1: How to make a host 'folder' prevent from being deleted, even if deleted it should ask **password** but still can read & write inside of it **without password**

Case 2: How to make a host 'folder' prevent from being deleted ***but this time the only way to deleting the 'host folder' is only with superuser do / sudo with ( terminal )*** but still can read & write inside of it **without password**

Case 3: Please tell me how to undo for both questions above

I want to make Folder like E.g : Folder  **Downloads**,**Movies**, **Picture**, etc. They can't be deleted but inside it's folder can be deleted easily

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for the first case(may not be conventional).

Create a folder wherever. Then create another folder inside the first one(for explaining purposes I shall call them f1 and f2). f2 will have all the files and folders you wish to be able to delete (and i recommend dragging it to your favourites tab in finder for ease of use).

Right click (or control+click) the folder f1 and click "Get Info". In the window that opens up under the "Sharing and Permissions:" section navigate to your username and take away the privilege of "Read & Write" and make it "Read only". This will make it so you cant delete folder f1 and f2 without entering your password but you can with your password and you can also read and write anything inside folder f2 without having to enter you password every time.

As for when you wish to undo this its as simple as simply right-clicking folder f1, clicking "Get Info" and giving yourself the permission to read and write again.

Edit : You could also lock the folder f1 instead of manually taking away as it essentially does the same thing(look for the text "Locked" with a box next to it)